# Not all data gets sent when sending response

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have an HTTPListener based .NET webserver, which generates data on request and outputs it. I am using StreamWriter to write to the output stream. When I write the data, not all of it gets received in Chrome, but all of it gets sent in the code. If I go to view source, it only shows part of the data that was sent.

It almost seems like some kind of timeout, or it getting too big, or something. Is there something that needs to be set in the HTTPListener or the request context?

Comment: Are you calling `Flush` on the stream before it gets sent?

Comment: No I was not, and yes, that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it was an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

Call `Flush` on the stream before it is sent.

Comment: Sent/Closed is mostly synonymous in this case, but yes, before being closed.